# The sum of numbers

Tags: python, list, sum, numbers

I've been making a program that finds two numbers in a random list and prints them if their sum is 8.
Honestly, I've been sitting here for half an hour and idk what's going on. I think I'm pretty close, but in rare cases it doesn't find an exitsting combination(list = [1,4,4,9] -> No combination). Also in rare cases I will get an error saying

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Here's my code:

```
import random
list = []
for i in range(1,5,1):
    newNum = random.randint(1,10)
    list.append(newNum)
list.sort()
sum = 8
print('\nRandomly generated list:')
print(list)
firstNum = list[0]
lastNum = list[-1]
newList = []
def isSum(a,b):
    if a + b == sum:
        if list.index(a) == list.index(b):
            print('\nThere isnt a combination.')
        else:
            newList.append(a)
            newList.append(b)
            print('\nCombination:')
            print(newList)
    elif a + b < sum:
        temp = list.index(a)
        temp += 1
        if temp > list.index(lastNum):
            print('\nThere isnt a combination.')
        else:
            a = list[temp]
            isSum(a,b)
    else:
        temp = list.index(b)
        temp -= 1
        if temp < list.index(firstNum):
            print('\nThere isnt a combination.')
        else:
            b = list[temp]
            isSum(a,b)
isSum(firstNum,lastNum)
```

**I'm just a beginner, don't get angry if I made a stupid mistake :3**

Comment: just looking at what you want to do, and the length of your code, you're making it more complicated than it has to be

Comment: I know XD but I don't know how to do it differently, I'm a newbie at python

Comment: One important note, don't name variables in a way that shadows a built in name (variable `list` shadows the built in `list` object or method)

Comment: I didn't know, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` module for generating all combinations of your list, then filter that by calculating the `sum` of each combination, for example this:

```py
import itertools


a = [1, 4, 4, 9]  # any list of nums
groups = 2
result = 8
combinations = [combination for combination in itertools.combinations(a, groups)]
output = [combination for combination in combinations if sum(combination) == result]

print(output)
>>> [(4, 4)]
```

Comment: And if there isn't a combination? Can I show a message?

Comment: @MirsenKahrovic you will get an empty list, you can use `if output:` to know if there is a correct combination and `else:` for when nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion really isn't ideal in Python, and your code could certainly be simplified.

---

This should return all the pairs.

```py
import itertools as itt
import random
from typing import List, Tuple


def is_comb_sum(nums: List[int], comb_size: int, target_sum: int) -> List[Tuple[int, ...]]:
    combs = []
    for curr_pair in itt.combinations(nums, comb_size):
        curr_sum = sum(curr_pair)
        if curr_sum == target_sum:
            combs.append(curr_pair)
    return combs


nums_list = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(5)]

print(nums_list)

res = is_comb_sum(nums_list, 2, 8)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print each combination once, you can use a set to identify the distinct numbers that are present.  Then, for each of these number, you determine which complementing value is need to reach your target (8) and if it is also in the set then the pair exists.  The only exception to this is when the number is exactly half of the target (i.e. 4) in which case you have to make sure there are at least two instances of that number in the list:

```
target  = 8
count   = 4

numbers = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(count)]    
print(numbers)

numberSet = set(numbers)
for number in numberSet:
    other = target-number
    if other not in numberSet: continue
    if other > number: continue # avoid duplicates such as 2+6=8 and 6+2=8
    if other == number and numbers.count(number) < 2: continue
    print(number,"+",other,"=",target)
```

Output:

```
[7, 2, 6, 1]
6 + 2 = 8
7 + 1 = 8
```

If you want to print all the combinations, you can use the Counter object from the collection modules and either print the number of occurrences or repeat the printed lines:

```
target  = 12
count   = 8

numbers = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(count)]    
print(numbers)

from collections import Counter
numberCounts = Counter(numbers)
for number in numberCounts:
    other = target-number
    if other > number: continue
    pairCount  = numberCounts[number] * numberCounts[other]
    if number == other:
        pairCount = (pairCount - numberCounts[number]) // 2
    if pairCount > 0:
        print(number,"+",other,"=",target,"occurred",pairCount,"time(s)")
```

Output (target of 12 in list of 8):

```
[7, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 3, 4]
7 + 5 = 12 occurred 2 time(s)
6 + 6 = 12 occurred 3 time(s)
```